# Apache If statement with AND and OR

Tags: apache, if-statement, redirect

I am running Apache 2.4.20 so I have no option to use nested if statement (2.4.26 I believe). I can't upgrade Apache unfortunately.

I am trying to redirect all HTTP requests to a specific secure URL. However 10.156.108.[2-3] are the firewall keepalives so I want to exclude them.

*If HTTPS is off and the remote IP is neither 10.156.108.[2-3] then redirect.*

**This obviously works but only for a specific IP:**

```
<If "%{HTTPS} == 'off' && %{REMOTE_HOST} != '10.156.108.2'">
    Redirect "/" https://www.example.com/ 
</If>
```

**This fails**

```
<If "%{HTTPS} == 'off' && (%{REMOTE_HOST} != '10.156.108.2' || %{REMOTE_HOST} != '10.156.108.3')">
    Redirect "/" https://www.example.com/
</If>
```

**This fails**

```
<If "%{HTTPS} == 'off' && %{REMOTE_HOST} != '10.156.108.[2-3]'">
    Redirect "/" https://www.example.com/
</If>
```

Any ideas, thanks.

Eddie

Answer (score 0):

Why does the second example fail? Because of parentheses? I think you have to put [spaces between parentheses](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html), probably like this:

```
<If "%{HTTPS} == 'off' && ( %{REMOTE_HOST} != '10.156.108.2' || %{REMOTE_HOST} != '10.156.108.3' )">
    Redirect "/" https://www.example.com/
</If>
```

You could also try to avoid parentheses altogether:

```
<If "%{HTTPS} == 'off' && %{REMOTE_HOST} != '10.156.108.2' && %{REMOTE_HOST} != '10.156.108.3'">
    Redirect "/" https://www.example.com/
</If>
```

Which should be logically identical to the first one.

I actually stumbled upon your question while researching how to use regex with Apache <If> directives, so the solution I'm going to use but adapted for your use case:

```
<If "%{HTTPS} == 'off' && %{REMOTE_HOST} !~ /10\.156\.108\.[23]/ ">
    Redirect "/" https://www.example.com/
</If>
```

**!~** denotes a [*string does not match the regular expression*](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) comparison operator and the following regex seems to be valid [when tested on Regexr](https://regexr.com/7ain2) (in your use case you can omit the g after the last forward slash I had to use there).

Hope one of these sticks. If nothing else works, this should:

```
<If "%{HTTPS} == 'off' && %{REMOTE_HOST} != '10.156.108.2'">
    Redirect "/" https://www.example.com/
</If>
<ElseIf "%{HTTPS} == 'off' && %{REMOTE_HOST} != '10.156.108.3">
    Redirect "/" https://www.example.com/
</ElseIf>
```